# when i delete a data that has been deleted from the Data Window but has not been committed to the database

Tags: sql-server, null, sql-delete, powerbuilder

when i delete a  data that has been deleted from the Data Window but has not been committed to the database. a null row is getting created in database... can anyone help me to solve this problem

Comment: Please provide more details. How you delete the data, which database you use?

Any code snippet?

Comment: Greko2009: to delete:                                                                           ELSEIF key=keyJ!  THEN
IF dw_detail.getselectedrow(0) = dw_detail.GetRow() THEN
dw_detail.scrolltorow (dw_detail.GetRow())
IF isnull( dw_detail.GetItemString(dw_detail.GetRow(),'discrep'))  THEN
messagebox("Error","No items are found!")
else
dw_detail.DeleteRow(dw_detail.GetRow() )
dw_detail.SetItemStatus(dw_detail.getselectedrow(0), 0, delete!, dataModified!)
il_currentrow --
if  dw_detail.Update() =1 then
COMMIT USING SQLCA;
else
messagebox("Warning","Do you want to delete?")
end if

Comment: and i am using sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try delete simple one row and delete it.

any inserts updates deletes need commit, add this:

```
if dw.update() = 1 then 
  commit;
else 
 rollback;
end if
```

Happy coding